# 301/404 Routing in Angular for *.aspx and other URLS

Tags: angular, http-status-code-404, angular2-routing, angular-cli

I have used angular-cli@1.2 verion and angular 2.
I have converted my old webform (asp.net with aspx page) sites to angular site and host in the same domain as my current webform site is hosted.
Hence, all of my old page url should redirect to my angular site with proper rewrite rules.

I want my old sites url which may or may not have *.aspx in its url (to handle 301) i.e from search engine they can hit to my angular site with *.aspx and other old url. I want to handle all those.

I have implemented routing rules in the application, but facing issue in 404 redirect module. If i tried to execute the unknown routing like

http://domainname/unknownpage  or  http://domainname/asdfdfsdf or http://domainname/loremipsum

=> it redirects me to HOME Page instead of 404 page.

If I can get a way around to execute 404 module instead of home page without affecting my current routing rules I can handle the old urls from there. But unfortunately, I face error in 404.

Can anyone with experience in Angular have come across with this kind of requirement. Please guide me. I am new to Angular 2

Below is the routing code in my application.

File Name:- app-routing.module.ts

```
import required files

const routes: Routes = [    

    { path: 'not-found', loadChildren: './not-found/not-found.module#NotFoundModule' },
    // { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: './front-end/front-end.module#FrontEndModule' ,
    },
    { path: '**', loadChildren: './not-found/not-found.module#NotFoundModule' },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

File Name:- front-end-routing.module.ts

```
import required files

var childrens = [
    { path: '', loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule' },
    { path: 'category', loadChildren: './category/category.module#VideosModule' },
    { path: 'product', loadChildren: './product/product.module#XpertModule' },
    { path: 'recovery', loadChildren: '../recovery/recovery.module#RecoveryModule' },
    { path: 'contactus', component: ContactusComponent },
];

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', component: FrontEndComponent,
        children: childrens
    }, {
        path: ':language', component: FrontEndComponent,
        children: childrens
    },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class FrontEndRoutingModule { }
```

Can i have something like 
 { path: '*.aspx', redirectTo: '404' },
  { path: '404', component: NotFoundComponent }

I tried the above one but not working.

May be I miss something in the routing rules. Let me know if I did.